# Sqlite3 syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite3

Alguém sabe o porquê desse erro? antes de usar o androidhelper estava funcionando, eu percebi que estava retornando um formato diferente, por isso transformei em string igual a um input comum:

```
def insert_password( service, username, password ):#Insere um serviço, com usuário e senha
    cursor.execute(f'
        INSERT INTO users (service, username, password)
        VALUES ('{service}', '{username}', '{password}')
    ')
    conn.commit()


while True:

    if op == 'i':# Caso o usuário deseja utilizar a função de inserir um serviço novo
        service = str(droid.dialogGetInput(" Qual é o serviço? "))
        username = str(droid.dialogGetInput(" Qual é o username? "))
        password = str(droid.dialogGetPassword(" Qual é a senha? "))
        insert_password( service, username, password)
        os.system('clear')
        droid.makeToast(' Salvo com successo')
        pausa()
```

**output:**

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "NovoServiço" 
>          :syntax error

Comment: Tenta retirar as aspas de dentro da query, por exemplo: f'
        INSERT INTO users (service, username, password)
        VALUES ({service}, {username}, {password})
    '

Comment: Removi as aspas e agora retornou=>  sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: Reult

Answer (score 2):

Não se trata de uma boa prática "montar" a sua string de consulta usando [`strings literais formatadas`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

O método [`Cursor.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) permite o uso de *placeholders* para esse propósito, veja só:

Solução #1 (*qmark style*):

```
def insert_password( service, username, password ):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (service, username, password) '
                   'VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )',
                   (service, username, password))
```

Solução #2:

```
def insert_password( service, username, password ):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (service, username, password) '
                   'VALUES ( :service, :username, :password )',
                   (service, username, password))
```

Solução #3 (*named style*):

```
def insert_password( **kwargs ):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (service, username, password) '
                   'VALUES ( :service, :username, :password )',
                   kwargs)

# Chamada da Função
insert_password(service='foobar3', username='fulano3', password='12345678')
```

Exemplo Funcional:

```
import sqlite3

def insert_password_v1( cursor, service, username, password ):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (service, username, password) '
                   'VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )',
                   (service, username, password))

def insert_password_v2( cursor, service, username, password ):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (service, username, password) '
                   'VALUES ( :service, :username, :password )',
                   (service, username, password))

def insert_password_v3( cursor, **kwargs ):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (service, username, password) '
                   'VALUES ( :service, :username, :password )',
                   kwargs)

conn = sqlite3.connect('foobar.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( service TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT );")

insert_password_v1( cur, 'serviço1', 'fulano1', '12345678' )
insert_password_v2( cur, 'serviço2', 'fulano2', 'aeiou' )
insert_password_v3( cur, service='serviço3', username='fulano3', password='qwerty' )

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Validando:

```
$ sqlite3 foobar.db 
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .headers ON
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> SELECT * FROM users;
service     username    password  
----------  ----------  ----------
serviço1   fulano1     12345678  
serviço2   fulano2     aeiou     
serviço3   fulano3     qwerty    
sqlite>
```